# Linux user rights www and no putty acces

Tags: linux, web, ssh, var, winscp

I have two users named pi who is root and pizza4yu. I have set chmod 777 to /var/www how can I set that pi has full access to that folder and pizza4yu has no access ? And also I have set that pizza4yu can use winscp but I want to deny shell access (putty) how to do that ?

Comment: sudo chmod -R u+w,go-w www   this command denied pizza4yu acces but no idea what it did. Pizza4yu can still use ssh how to prevent that ?

Answer (score 1):

do this from root:

```
chmod 700 /var/www
```

this will give full access to pi and no access to pizza4yu. For denying ssh access to pizza4yu, remove the public key of pizza4yu from ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. Also look in the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

Comment: chmod 700 will not work if pizza4yu will be the owner of all /var/www

Comment: but pizza4yu is not the root as OP said, then is it possible that pizza4yu could be the owner of /var/www?Since /var/www is owned by root.

Comment: in default yes, but we don't know it in this case

Comment: OP himself said this in the very first line of his question

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that pizza4yu is not owner (by username or group) of /var/www, for example by:

```
ls -l /var/www
```

Then you will need to remove privilages for users usning (run it as root or as /var/www owner):

```
chmod -R u-rwx /var/www
```

EDIT:
If PI is not owner of /var/www and you want to make him, then use

```
chown -R PI /var/www
```

Comment: Dont know what happened but after that I cant use Filezilla to transfer files with PI ?

Comment: It means that PI isn't owner of whole /var/www but if you want to, then use command:
chown -R PI /var/www